# return conditional week days using reduceRight

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, lodash

i am trying to get specific week(such as saturday) days collection from my mongodb. here is the example DB collection

```
var array2 = [
{
"_id": "1",
"start": "2016-08-23T16:00:00.000Z",
},
{
"_id": "2",
"start": "2016-08-26T21:00:00.000Z",
},
{
"_id": "3",
"start": "2016-08-23T16:10:00.000Z",
}];
```

[javascript week reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getutcday.asp)
to get Saturday entry i run a map, and here is the code

```
array2.map(function(object){ 
 var newObject = {};
 var nedatee = new Date(object.start);
 var weekday = nedatee.getDay();
 if (weekday===6) {
     newObject['start'] = true;
 }
 return newObject;
});
```

the output is

> [ {}, {'start':true}, {}]

i dont want the empty object in my array, and i dont want to manually remove it, is there any smarted way? how can i make good use of reduceRight ?
all i want is

> [{'start':true}]

[javascript map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) reference if you need

Comment: did u try using `mapReduce` on db itself

Comment: Use [*filter*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.filter), which creates a new array based on the elements that return *true* from the callback function. Or if you want to modify the array itself, use [*reduceRight*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.reduceright) and splice the failures.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing elements with Array.map in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289/removing-elements-with-array-map-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use *reduceRight* and splice the failures:

```js
var array2 = [
{
"_id": "1",
"start": "2016-08-23T16:00:00.000Z",
},
{
"_id": "2",
"start": "2016-08-26T21:00:00.000Z",
},
{
"_id": "3",
"start": "2016-08-23T16:10:00.000Z",
}];

array2.reduceRight(function(acc,v,i) {
  if (new Date(v.start).getUTCDay() != 6){
    array2.splice(i,1);
  }
},null)

console.log(array2);
```

Note that the date will be parsed as UTC, so 2016-08-26T21:00:00.000Z will be Saturday in any timezone that is UTC+0300 or more, hence use of *getUTCDay* (i.e. none of the days is Saturday in the GMT time zone).

Also, you should not really rely on parsing any date string with the Date constructor. You should use a parser and provide the format, see [*Chrome can't parse date but IE can*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39046996/chrome-cant-parse-date-but-ie-can/39069608#39069608).

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using javascript some? Your code would then be

```
var hasSaturdays = array2.some(function isSaturday(object){ 
 var nedatee = new Date(object.start);
 return nedatee.getDay() === 6;
});
```

Then if hasSaturdays is true then you can return `[{'start':true}]`

Please note that it is only IE 9+

Comment: Note that this parses the date as UTC but does the comparison as local, so it will give different results in different time zones.

Answer (score 2):

Using UTC time zone or not this is a simple filtering work and there is `Array.prototype.filter()` just for this job.

```js
var array2 = [
{
"_id": "1",
"start": "2016-08-23T16:00:00.000Z",
},
{
"_id": "2",
"start": "2016-08-26T21:00:00.000Z",
},
{
"_id": "3",
"start": "2016-08-23T16:10:00.000Z",
}],
saturdays = array2.filter(date => (new Date(date.start)).getDay() === 6)
                  .map(date => ({start:true}));
console.log(saturdays);
```